# Always Null Reference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

So many thread about this problem. But I can't find how to fix it. Can anyone tell me where do I go wrong in my code?

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   PlayerWeaponController.EquipWeapon (.Item itemToEquip(atAssets/Scripts/PlayerWeaponController.cs:33)
>   InventoryController.Update ((atAssets/Scripts/Inventory/InventoryController.cs:61)

And here is the code for player weapon controller

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerWeaponController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject playerHand;
    public GameObject EquippedWeapon { get; set; }

    IWeapon equippedWeapon;
    CharacterStats characterStats;

    void Start()
    {
        characterStats = GetComponent<CharacterStats>();
    }

    public void EquipWeapon(Item itemToEquip)
    {
        if (EquippedWeapon != null)
        {

            characterStats.RemoveStatBonus(EquippedWeapon.GetComponent<IWeapon>().Stats);
            Destroy(playerHand.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        }


        EquippedWeapon = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Weapons/" + itemToEquip.ObjectSlug), 
            playerHand.transform.position, playerHand.transform.rotation);
        equippedWeapon = EquippedWeapon.GetComponent<IWeapon>();
        equippedWeapon.Stats = itemToEquip.Stats;
        EquippedWeapon.transform.SetParent(playerHand.transform);
        characterStats.AddStatBonus(itemToEquip.Stats);
        Debug.Log(equippedWeapon.Stats[0]);


    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
            PerformWeaponAttack();
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
            //PerformWeaponSpecialAttack();
    }

    public void PerformWeaponAttack()
    {
        equippedWeapon.PerformAttack();
    }

}
```

and here is the code for inventory controller

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventoryController : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerWeaponController playerWeaponController;
    public List<Item> playerItems = new List<Item>();
    public Item sword;

    void Start()
    {

        playerWeaponController = GetComponent<PlayerWeaponController>();
        List<BaseStat> swordStats = new List<BaseStat>();
        swordStats.Add(new BaseStat(6, "Power", "Your power level."));
        sword = new Item(swordStats, "sword");
    }

    public void EquipItem(Item itemToEquip)
    {
        playerWeaponController.EquipWeapon(itemToEquip);
    } 


    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            playerWeaponController.EquipWeapon(sword);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the item

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item {
    public List<BaseStat> Stats { get; set; }
    public string ObjectSlug { get; set; }

    public Item(List<BaseStat> _Stats, string _ObjectSlug)
    {
        this.Stats = _Stats;
        this.ObjectSlug = _ObjectSlug;
    }
}
```

this the basestat

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class BaseStat
{

    public List<StatBonus> BaseAdditives { get; set; }
    public int BaseValue { get; set; }
    public string StatName { get; set; }
    public string StatDescription { get; set; }
    public int FinalValue { get; set; }

    public BaseStat(int baseValue, string statName, string statDescription)
    {
        this.BaseAdditives = new List<StatBonus>();
        this.BaseValue = baseValue;
        this.StatName = statName;
        this.StatDescription = statDescription;
    }

    public void AddStatBonus(StatBonus statBonus)
    {

        this.BaseAdditives.Add(statBonus);
    }

    public void RemoveStatBonus(StatBonus statBonus)
    {
        this.BaseAdditives.Remove(BaseAdditives.Find(x=> x.BonusValue == statBonus.BonusValue));
    }

    public int GetCalculatedStatValue()
    {
        this.FinalValue = 0;
        this.BaseAdditives.ForEach(x => this.FinalValue += x.BonusValue);
        this.FinalValue += BaseValue;
        return FinalValue;
    }

}
```

and this characterstat

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CharacterStats: MonoBehaviour {
    public List<BaseStat> stats = new List<BaseStat>();

    private void Start()
    {
        stats.Add(new BaseStat(4, "Power", "Your power level."));
        stats.Add(new BaseStat(2, "Vitality", "Your vitality level."));
    }


    public void AddStatBonus(List<BaseStat> statBonuses)
    {
        foreach(BaseStat statBonus in statBonuses)
        {

            stats.Find(x=> x.StatName == statBonus.StatName).AddStatBonus(new StatBonus(statBonus.BaseValue));
        }
    }



    public void RemoveStatBonus(List<BaseStat> statBonuses)
    {
        foreach (BaseStat statBonus in statBonuses)
        {

            stats.Find(x => x.StatName == statBonus.StatName).RemoveStatBonus(new StatBonus(statBonus.BaseValue));
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

It solved, I'm not inserting sword script to sword object. sorry and thanks for all

Comment: Why have you included the [java] tag?

Answer (score 0):

So it's failing when trying to set the stats from the passed in `itemToEquip` parameter. This is due to it, or it's Stats property being `null`.

It appears this is being setup in the `InventoryController`, where is `InventoryController.EquipItem` being called from? Specifically we'll need to know where the input `"Item"` that is supposed to flow into that method comes from?

If you haven't already, please attempt to reference a specific element in the `itemToEquip.Stats` List.

For example:

`equippedWeapon.Stats = itemToEquip.Stats[0];`

OR (via use of ElementAt extention method):

`equippedWeapon.Stats = itemToEquip.Stats.ElementAt(0);`

Comment: sorry i can't understand

Comment: so where shall i put that code?

Comment: Assets/Scripts/PlayerWeaponController.cs(33,49): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `BaseStat' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<BaseStat>'

its the error when i put that code

Comment: You made some updates to actually populate the stats at an element I read below, what problems are you running into now or did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should check `null` condition for `itemToEquip` parameter  or the **exact error throwing object**.

```
if(itemToEquip!=null)
{
equippedWeapon.Stats = itemToEquip.Stats;
}
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Still are you getting the same error? @OctavianWibawaReksa

Comment: yep, even if you delete these code, it still error

Comment: Which line you are getting the error? @OctavianWibawaReksa

Comment: aah, if you delete line 33 equippedWeapon.Stats = itemToEquip.Stats; and 36 Debug.Log(equippedWeapon.Stats[0]); its work. but i think i will need that code for continuing my game